# Mock CSS property not supported for testing?

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser

I need to test my website as if different CSS properties aren't supported. Is there a way you can disable support for certain properties, such as 3D transforms?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest, fastest and most reliable solution is to use an old version of a browser -- since that's the most likely real-world scenario in which various CSS properties would be unsupported.

eg:  You can find old versions of Chrome (Windows) here:  (including the pre-1.0 beta) http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome/

Answer (score 3):

This is kind-of a hacky solution, but you could use the universal selector to reset all elements to the default value for the property, with `!important`. So long as you are not using `!important` in your code, this should be a pretty accurate simulation.

## Example (disables `transform`):

```
* {
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
       -moz-transform: none !important;
        -ms-transform: none !important;
         -o-transform: none !important;
            transform: none !important;
}
```

You could even inject this code from your browsers developer tools.

Unfortunately, this won't work for a subset of supported properties.

Answer (score 2):

In short, probably not. But you might be able to simulate this by using a structured CSS (possibly LESS/SASS) file, so you can simply disable chunks of rules to see what it looks.

If your goal is to simply see how it reacts across older browsers, then this isn't the best simulation - it's rather academic. Instead, you might want to use one of the many systems that will test a web page for you and send you the output.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to test CSS properties in **real browsers**. I know it might be almost impossible to get all needed browser testing versions installed in your computer so there is a nice web service that provides a testing environment:

- https://www.browserstack.com/

In addition you can check CSS availability in:

- http://caniuse.com/